# How to use sql-injection package in Node.js application?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I want to prevent my app for SQL-Injection attack in Node.js,for that i am using **sql-inection** package of NPM.
My **app.js** File

```
var app = express();
var sqlinjection = require('sql-injection');
app.use(sqlinjection);
```

With this configuration i am directly sending request to server.
But with each request to the server the api does not send any response and gives no error or Warning.

I am using this Npm package [sql injection npm js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sql-injection)

Please guide me to how to use sql-injection in **node.js** and **express.js** project.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you please provide a full code example of your app.js file?

Comment: Have you configured added Express routes? What version of Express and nodejs are you using? As @AshleyB has already said, please post your `app.js` file's contents - it's very difficult to troubleshoot without your actual code.

Comment: For sql injection i used above code,other code are confedential and they are unrelated to sql-injection

Comment: Not really, you're asking why it is becoming un-responsive - which could be many other reasons other than the package. Please provide a the rest of the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please include following lines in your **app.js** file

```
app.use('/wordcloud',wordcloud);
app.use('/profanityfilter',profanityfilter);
app.use('/api/notification',notification);
app.use('/api/badge',badgecount);
app.use('/api/csrf',csrfRoute);
app.use(sqlinjection);
```

**After requiring the npm package you must use this sql-injection package at the end of all your router.
and it will work fine.**